# jQuery ajaxComplete, ajaxSuccess deprecated?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I used to use `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {});` to check if the page have all the ajax calls finish running.

I read jQuery 1.8+ deprecated `.ajaxComplete` and `.ajaxSuccess`. Is there any alternatives that I can check if the page have completed all the ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

It has not been deprecated, check the docs for `ajaxComplete()` http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

> **As of jQuery 1.8, the `.ajaxComplete()` method should only be attached to document.**
>
> All ajaxComplete handlers are invoked, regardless of what Ajax request was completed. If you must differentiate between the requests, use the parameters passed to the handler. Each time an ajaxComplete handler is executed, it is passed the event object, the XMLHttpRequest object, and the settings object that was used in the creation of the request.

And most importantly:

> If `$.ajax()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` is called with the global option set to false, the `.ajaxComplete()` method will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your requirement is slightly different from the functionality of `.ajaxComplete()`. `.ajaxComplete()` is fired **whenever *any* AJAX calls are completed** on the page, not when *all* calls are completed.

If you want to make sure that all calls are completed before you call a handler, you will have to store all your AJAX requests into an array, and ensure that they're all complete using `$.when.apply($, array)`, for example:

```
var ajaxCalls = [];

// Make ajax calls
var call1 = $.get(...);
ajaxCalls.push(call1);

// Rinse and repeat the above pattern

// Fire function when ALL AJAX calls are completed
$.when.apply($, ajaxCalls).then(function() {
    // When ALL ajax calls in the array are successful
}, function() {
    // When one or more of the ajax calls have failed
});
```